# React-Redux createStore throwing "Error: Expected the reducer to be a function" when combineReducer passed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Good evening, It seems that I am having some issue with the `createStore` function.

This is the entire `store.js` file

```
// Import required redux functions
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
// Import thunk for async redux reducers
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
// import the main reducer
import rootReducer from './reducers';
console.log(rootReducer); // log the value of the root reducer to the console for inspection
// Define the store as a constant so it acts like a singleton (for authentication reasons this is helpfull)
const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension : f => f
));
console.log(store); // log the store to the console for inspection (does not happen)
// export it as the default object
export default store;
```

And the simple `reducers/index.js` file:

```
// Import the core function
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
// Import all the reducers
import loginReducer from './loginReducer'; // a simple working reducer for handling the jwt token

console.log(loginReducer); // log the reducer for inspection
// export the combination of reducers within their own subroutes
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // TODO add reducers with keys like so
  login: loginReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

And the `loginreducer.js` file:

```
// the default state configuration
const initialState = {logged_in: false, error: null, token: null}
// login reducer
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) { // check the type of action that was passed in
    case "LOGIN_ERROR": // error during the login process
      return {logged_in: false, error: action.error, token: null}
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS": // login was successfull or....
    case "LOGIN_NEW_TOKEN": // client has recived a new token
      return {logged_in: true, error: null, token: action.token}
    case "LOG_OUT": // the client has logged out
      localStorage.removeItem('token'); // remove the token from storage
      return initialState // return the inital state (not logged in)
    default:
      return state // return the current state (a.k.a take no action)
  }
}
```

This throws the custom error `Error: Expected the reducer to be a function` defined on line 46 (https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L46, 55 in the built version) of `createStore.js`:

```
if (typeof reducer !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('Expected the reducer to be a function.');
  }
```

However, when I use the chrome debugging tools to save the `rootReducer` to the console (as `temp1`) and check it's type it is indeed `"function"`.

[image: chrome_debugging_screenshot]

adding a breakpoint on the condition in `createStore.js` shows me that `reducer` is set to `undefined`, any idea how it can be defined for the `console.log` call but is not defined when it is passed to a function on the next line?

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the code for the loginReducer as well ?

Comment: @klugjo Sure, I added it now. Not sure it helps it is quite generic

Comment: I got it. Can't believe I missed it entirely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good evening,

I found the issue. in `store.js` I forgot to add `()` after the `devToolsExtension` call. or in other words this:

```
window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension : f => f
```

should look like this:

```
window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
```

Simple but annoying.